# How do I set an Azure WebJob to run every N number of hours

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-webjobssdk, azure-webjobs-continuous

I have an Azure webjob that was created as a console application and published to azure via Visual studio.

When I login to the portal, I can see the web-job is running, but I want it to run every 1 hour.

How can I do this? Schedule seems to say n/a 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

use Hangfire and schedule to run every one hour:

```
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(() => Console.WriteLine("This job will execute once in every minute"), Cron.Hourly);
```

Change the Web Job to Azure Functions and use the time trigger:

```
 public static void Run([TimerTrigger("* 0 */1 * * *", RunOnStartup=true)]TimerInfo myTimer, TraceWriter log)
{
//code
}
```

more info:

https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-scheduled-function

Answer (score 0):

Use a "triggered/scheduled" WebJob instead of a continuous one.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-create#CreateScheduledCRON

[image]